# NSTextStorage - How to find return chars (new line) in a text

Tags: objective-c, nstextstorage

In an NSTextStorage I insert time strings at the current pointer location like this :

```
            NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"00:00:00"];
            [attrString autorelease];
            int pos = [self selectedRange].location;
            [[self textStorage] insertAttributedString: attrString atIndex:pos];
```

So far so good, it works perfect. But now I want to position the pointer at the beginning of the next line. Obviously this is right after the next return char.

Now how to find the next return char in `textStorage` and position the pointer there ?
I have not found any hint in the web for this task. Please help ...

Comment: With "pointer" you mean "cursor"?

Comment: with pointer I mean cursor, yes

Comment: Technically it is a selection (with zero length) stored in the view. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a method to set the cursor (more precise: selection with zero length) in `NSTextStorage`'s API, because it is a storage, having no selection. The selection is a property of the text view. This is the result of MVC. Simply do a check: You can have many text views displaying the same text. Obviously each one needs its own selection.

What you have to do is to get the position of the next paragraph (this is better than searching for `\n`) and set this as a selection for the text view.

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"00:00:00"];
[attrString autorelease]; // You should *really* use ARC
int pos = [self selectedRange].location;
[[self textStorage] insertAttributedString: attrString atIndex:pos];

// Get the next paragraph
NSString *text = self.textStorage.string;
NSRange restOfStringRange = NSMakeRange( pos, [text length]-pos );
NSUInteger nextParagraphIndex;

// You have to look to the start of the next paragraph
[text getParagraphStart:&nextParagraphIndex end:NULL contentsEnd:NULL forRange:restOfStringRange];

NSTextView *view = self.textView; // Or where ever you get it from
view.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(nextParagraphIndex, 0);
```

Typed in Safari, not tested, just to show the basic approach.

Comment: Your answer seems to go to the right direction. It looks good, I tested it. But after insertion the cursor jumps back to the position where he has been before. How to find the end of the paragraph ?

Comment: After insertion? My code is intended to run after the insertion. I added your complete code to show that.

Comment: Yes, your code runs after insertion, as you showed it. And works perfect so far. But the cursor jumps to the beginning of the text where he was before. I expected the cursor to jump to the next line (at the end of the text which was inserted)

Comment: Well, check the value of `nextParagraphIndex`. Is that correct? (Is it at the next paragraph?) If not, change the search. If yes, you probably have to delay the setting of the selected range. Just test it and post the result in a comment to my answer.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your last comment. But Let me make a simple example : There are 2 lines of text, each line has 10 characters. In the beginning the cursor position is zero 0). At this position a string with 5 chars is inserted. The first line is extend by 5 chars and the lentgh of the entire text grows by 5 chars. To position the cursors at the beginning of the 2nd line the cursors location must be 15. But your example results in zero (0).

Comment: I clarify my comment: In such a case, does already `nextParagraphIndex` have the value of zero or it is 15, but the cursor is set to 0 anyway? The reason for my Q: If your selected range is 0 when you enter the code, this is the beginning of first paragraph in the range. In such a case you have to add 1. But I cannot now that, because I do not have your test data. So please run the code with a breakpoint after `-getParagraphIndex:…` and post the value of the index here.

Comment: There ist no `-getParagraphIndex:…`. Do you mean `getParagraphStart:&nextParagraphIndex`? The value of this is zero (0) after inserting a string at the start of line 1.

Comment: Your are writing "In such a case you have to add 1". What does it mean exactly ?

Comment: Would please comment the result from debugger?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96769/discussion-between-ben-and-amin-negm-awad).